# Load search result in same page thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have very little understanding on thymeleaf and i dont use it almost at all, i would like to enter something in searchbox, press search and just get result of the search (if exists) in the same page.

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en"> <title></title>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">


        <h2>Search for monter</h2>
        <!--/*@thymesVar id="monter" type="com.atlas.model.Monter" */-->
        <form th:object="${monter}" th:action="@{/}" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
            <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(search)}">
                <h2>monter List</h2>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>

                    </tr>
                    <!--/*@thymesVar id="monter" type="com.atlas.model.Monter" */-->
                    <tr th:each="monter: ${search}">
                        <!--/*@thymesVar id="monter" type="com.atlas.model.Monter" */-->
                        <td th:text="${monter.id}"><a href="/monter/${monter.id}">Well</a></td>
                        <td th:text="${monter.name}">Well</td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(search)}">
               <h2>No entry matches that name!</h2>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

following upon that here is my controller

```
  @Controller
public class MyController {
    private  final MonterServiceImpl monterService;

    public MyController(MonterServiceImpl monterService) {
        this.monterService = monterService;
    }


    @RequestMapping({"", "/", "/index"})
    public String getIndexPage() {
        System.out.println("booh");

        return "index";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "monters", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMonterName(@RequestParam(value = "search",required = false) String name, Model model) {

        System.out.println(monterService.findMonterByName(name));
        model.addAttribute("search", monterService.findMonterByName(name));
        return "/";



    }
}
```

now this does work and i do get a loaded page, and i know my backed works i tested the search function, i get the monter when i search with just backend.

EDIT

I cleaned up my code, i think im kinda closer to solution, however i just get no error or anything,i dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: You can use thymeleaf fragment and ajax for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

i was returning non existant page, silly from me,
updated the question